# Rmd output format not compiled correctly in blogdown when HTML file already exists

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I have a webpage ([www.vegardlysne.no](http://www.vegardlysne.no)) built with blogdown, using the academic theme. In one section of my page, I publish my notes taken during conferences and courses I attend, and I want them to be knitted with a different output format. I store these .Rmd files in the static folder, and specified a "build.R" script to knit .Rmd files in the static folder to HTML before compiling the page.

Specifically, I want to knit these files with theme: darkly and a floating toc, properly specified in the YAML header. This has worked perfectly before, and in principle still works when compiling an Rmd file for the first time.

The problem, however, occur when the Rmd file is updated when they have been previously knitted (corresponding HTML file exists in the static folder). When I update the Rmd file, the HTML file lose the formatting and is compiled as text on white background, with the YAML header as a single line at the top like this:

--- title: "My title" output: html_document: toc: true toc_depth: 2 toc_float: true theme: darkly ---

I can escape the problem by deleting the HTML file in the static folder before running blogdown::build_site(). Then the HTML is knitted properly, but once I make changes to the Rmd file, the problem reoccurs.

I don't know what causes this behavior, and would appreciate any input. I have not updated the theme (Academic 4.6.0) or hugo version (0.59.1, minimum required for the theme version is 0.58). I have the latest version of R and Rstudio.

Comment: How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You might have run into [a bug that was fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/3bed02cdae920410353a5af7fcb4f85f5acb4093) two months ago in the [development version of **blogdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown):

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Please restart R, and try to knit the document again.